# Android Studio AVD on Chromebook

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome-os

I am running Android Studio on a Chromebook.  It is listed as one of Google's suggested Chromebooks for running Android Studio.  I have it installed but I cannot run anything as it seems the emulator/AVD is not working/enabled.   I have enabled developer mode but it does not appear to work.  Is there a way to make this work and/or is there a work-around, e.g., (not ideal) could I just run the APK somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The capability to debug directly Android application on ChromeOS (sideloading them) has been announced at the Android Developer Summit 2019.

[This should be added to ChromeOS v80](https://www.aboutchromebooks.com/news/chrome-os-80-to-bring-arc-sideloading-of-android-apps-to-chromebooks/).